# Remove coating from chrome headlights

Tags: paint, restoration, moped

I'm restoring an old moped. It's a **1964 NSU Quickly N23**.

[image: NSU Quickly N23]

One of the next steps on my restoration project is to work on the paint and chrome parts. My headlights are covered with a layer of paint. I'm not sure what exactly it is but I suspect it's some kind of zinc coating (I might be wrong though).

[image: The headlight as a whole]

I scratched away some of the outer coating to reveal a shiny chrome layer underneath:

[image: A chrome layer showing up on the headlights]

I'd love to remove the outer coating to surface the original chrome again but I don't know how to approach this. I thought about carefully sanding the headlights to get rid of the outer coating but I'm worried that this will destroy the chrome more than necessary. I was wondering if there was another way to remove the outer coating while keeping the original coating and chrome intact.

I know that the headlights are pretty beat up. I don't expect to reveal spotless chrome underneath. Still, I'd love to get a little closer to the original look of the headlights and get rid of the outer coating. Any ideas how I could pull this off?

(if it helps, I think [this is what the original headlight might've looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cynvw.jpg). A mix of chrome and clear coated paint)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Cool project by the way!

Comment: There are places that will redo the chrome.

Comment: Looking at other pictures it seems like the entire front ring of the headlight was chrome and the body of the headlight was painted.

Comment: @SolarMike fair point. Sandblasting, sanding and re-painting is a good way to solve this. It's not exactly the look I'm going for, though. I like the rust, the patina, the dents and imperfections as they tell a story. And the original NSU Quickys weren't polished high-gloss mopeds anyways. If possible, I'd prefer to "just" remove the coating that was applied after the fact to get closer to the original state. Redoing the paint and chrome sounds like a good plan B if that turns out to be impossible (or I mess up along the way).

Comment: Ahh, so this is not a “factory spec” restoration or a “concours” restoration then.

Comment: You might try "walnut hull" blasting.  The chrome should be hard enough to stand up to the walnut shells while the paint coating should come off.

Comment: Chemical Paint stripper.